# Android Studio: The following classes could not be instantiated

Tags: android

I want to use the Library "ProcessButtons" in my Android Project but i get this error:

Link to picture: http://postimg.org/image/82m27ee1l/

I have add the Library like this:

File -> Project Structures -> app -> Dependencies

This is the exeption:

```
java.lang.InstantiationException
at sun.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.java:48)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:374)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:99)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallback.loadView(LayoutlibCallback.java:172)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:135)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:755)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:373)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:399)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:336)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:332)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$3.compute(RenderService.java:575)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$3.compute(RenderService.java:564)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:932)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:564)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.render(RenderService.java:691)
at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$6.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:483)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:327)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Hope you can help me.

Thanks, Jonah.

Comment: does knowbody knows an answer?